# Show recurring events only if they are upcoming soon

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, recurring-events

I have an events web part at a hub site that rolls up calendar items from site calendars. The issue now is that someone has added recurring events to the calendar, like New Year´s Day. The events web part now shows this event on top of the events list. So according to the Events WP, New Year´s Day next year will be upcoming before events that will happen tomorrow and next week. Also another recurring holiday in January next year is more upcoming than the events that are upcoming soon.
None of the filters for the Events WP will filter away or denote those upcoming events.
It look like New Year´s Days is an event that will go on for 27 years...

As we are getting closer to Easter, more of these recurring events will occupy the top position of the events WP, and soon no other upcoming events except recurring events will show on the list.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I really hope that this bug will be fixed.

But I used the following workaround for yearly events:
When the date for the recurring event has passed, locate which of the sites connected to the hub that has the recurring event. Edit this event so that the first occurrence will be next year. The drawback is that you lose history, but without any workaround the event web part is not usable.